# Model relation not being set in Laravel. Why?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Sorry for the short question title, this absurdly simple thing doesn't work and I have no idea why. I'm trying to manually set the key on a model relation in Laravel (why manually? I need to compare the current key to what I'm setting it to, to see if there's been a change; as far as I know there's no other way of doing this):

```
$this->mission->featured_image = $input['featured_image'];
```

Where `$input['featured_image']` is 3. [Proof](https://i.imgur.com/2thyv9M.png).

A Featured Image is a relation defined as such on my `Mission` model:

```
class Mission extends Eloquent {
    public function featuredImage() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Object', 'featured_image');
    }    
}
```

#### Schema

[image]

After stepping through the assignment, `$this->mission->featured_image` remains null, despite that what I am assigning it isn't. Thoughts?

Comment: Is Object one of your Eloquent Models? I think you're doing something way too wrong!

Comment: I'm storing the primary key of `Object` in the `featured_image` column of my `Mission` table.

Comment: Can you post the tables with PK and FK?

Comment: Added. Shouldn't be relevant though since I'm only trying to set the foreign key `featured_image` manually.

Comment: Try $this->mission->save() and see what happens

Comment: I'm already doing that.

Comment: It's possible there may be a conflict due to the name of your relationship matching the name of the foreign key. Try changing the name of your relationship method to be different than the name of a field on the table. (i.e. `featuredImage` snake-cased is `featured_image`; try renaming `featuredImage`)